# Get date fields list of an index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i am beginner in elasticsearch
i want to write a query in elasticsearch to return field names which are date (type=date).

> for example in **index3** i want to return **inserttime** , **@timestamp** and **time_date**

```
{
  "index3" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "money" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "time_date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        }
        "parent": {
            "properties": {
              "inserttime": {
                "type": "date"
              },
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to leverage the [`jq` JSON utility](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
curl -s -XGET localhost:9200/index3 | jq '.index3.mappings.properties | with_entries(select(.value.type | contains("date")))'
```

Running the above command would yield

```
{
  "@timestamp": {
    "type": "date"
  },
  "time_date": {
    "type": "date"
  }
}
```

With Angular, it's even easier:

```
const indexBody = { "index3: ... };
const dateFields = [];
Object.keys(indexBody.index3.mappings.properties).forEach(field => {
    if (indexBody.index3.mappings.properties[field].type == 'date') {
        dateFields.push(field);
    }
});

console.log(dateFields);
```

=> Results

```
[ '@timestamp', 'time_date' ]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works but is not dynamic! if there was object field that contains date field inside itself it does't work correctly

Comment: Well, you see the logic, you can modify it to your liking. It works based on the example you provided.

Comment: yes, but as i saied before your answer didnt work in nested mapping ... i want to return all date fields...

Comment: Well, I showed you the way, but you actually want me to code your solution...?